# How to get special data in table, to use String Equation IN JAVA

Tags: java, string, transformation, equation

Product Table /
Price column / Alias C1 / data [100000, 600000, 800000, 200000 ...]

example ==> (C1>700000?0.5:2)*20 > 20 AND C1 <80000"
I input example text equation at textarea control.

When entering a example and clicking a button, I want to extract only a specific line.

I want to show only the results that correspond to the expression.

so, How can I convert a textual representation of a search expression to something that can be executed in Java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA - Expression parsing & evaluating library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947553/java-expression-parsing-evaluating-library)

Comment: you can also read https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-java/

Comment: Added English narrative to clarify the question. Added markup to show the kind of queries that might be used.

Comment: Since java 9 JShell with its REPL can be used. Or the java scripting API.