# Parsing JSON and Evaluating expressions from its fields

Tags: java, json, spring, expression-evaluation

I have a JSON document from which I have figured a way of parsing and extracting the values within it using the library of [JSON-Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

I have to evaluate rules/expressions using the variables in the parsed JSON.

For example:

`{maxAge:25, minAge:20, age:25}`

- rule1 : $.maxAge-$.minAge>100 then send alert
- rule2 : $.age<18 then send alert

What libraries are available in Java for the same ?

Comment: What is your question? Did you try anything to achieve it?

Comment: the question is to have a simple java program that will evaluate rules similar to the one mentioned above and generate an alert. I'm stuck at the rule evaluation part.

Comment: Rules will be read from a property file. I've used JSON path doesn't have to be a JSON path. can be anything simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way, apparently, I don't need a JSON path. I can use javascript directly inside my code. so I've written rules in javascript

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine jsEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        String json = "{\"maxAge\":25, \"minAge\":20, \"age\":25}";
        String rule = "(x.maxAge)-(x.minAge) > 0;";

        jsEngine.put("x", json);

        try {
            jsEngine.eval("function test(abc){" + "var x=JSON.parse(abc);" + "return " + rule + "}");

            Invocable inv = (Invocable) jsEngine;
            boolean result = (Boolean) inv.invokeFunction("test", json);
            if (result) {
                System.out.println("Alert rule triggered");
            }

        } catch (ScriptException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Json Path will only let you parse the JSON file and read the variables within it. You have to use a separate Java library for evaluating the expressions. Take a look at a this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947553/java-expression-parsing-evaluating-library) which discuss the same.

Another useful post that I found on purely mathematical expression evaluation is [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-evaluate-math-expression-string) one.

It would be helpful if you can identify all the operators that will be part of the expression. For ex, Arithmetic Operators ( +, -, /, *. ), Equality and Relational Operators ( =, !=, <, > )

Answer (score 0):

There are several java libraries that allow you to parse JSON. Two major ones are Jackson-JSON and Gson. Both are de-facto standard. My personal preference is Jackson.

Here is the simplest way to parse JSON:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModules(new JavaTimeModule());
ObjectReader objectReader= objectMapper.reader();
Map<String, Object>data = objectReader.forType(Map.class).readValue(s);
```

Here are the needed maven artifacts

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.3</version>        
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is github site: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson.
Here is relevant [Javadoc](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)